# magento 2 apply default discount code

Tags: checkout, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.3, discount, coupon

I am working on magento 2.3.0 and checkout is working fine with discount.

I have created discount code named **95TEST** which discount 95% on order total.

Now, Every time when customer redirect to checkout page, above discount code 95TEST automatically applied. No need to do customer to enter discount code.

How to apply discount code automatically?

Regards
Hiren SHah